# ASP NET GET SIMPLE ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Amigos tengo un get Simple en ASP NET al que llamo de la siguiente manera

> https://localhost:44309/DashboardAdmin/CheckRoleExist/admin

Bueno este es mi controlador

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CheckRoleExist(string n)
    {
        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {
            var role = db.AspNetRoles.ToList<AspNetRoles>().Where(u => u.Name.Equals(n)).FirstOrDefault(); 

            return Json(role, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

la cuestion está en que **n** siempre llega **null** alguien sabe porque me está pasando? llamo a otros gets donde les mando string o int y lo recibo sin problmeas. Alguien ve algo que yo no?

Comment: que no deberia ser `https://localhost:44309/DashboardAdmin/CheckRoleExist?n=admin`

Comment: listo ya llegó, pero esta raro, es la primera vez que me aconsejan algo así, siempre lo había mandado sobre la url sin problemas

Comment: Agrega el archivo donde defines tus rutas :D

Comment: es asp.net o asp.net mvc ?

Comment: mvc @LeandroTuttini

Comment: lo imagine, por eso cambie el tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes enviarlo como lo mencionas pero para eso deberias revisar el `routing`

[Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

se se configuro algo como ser

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

el valor va a mapear con un parametro `id`, no con uno `n`, por eso veras se se recibe en un metodo con el parametro con ese nombre en el verbo get

```
[HttpGet]
public Product FindProduct(id) {}
```

Sino una alternativa si es que usas `asp.net mvc 5` puedes definir el routing como atributo

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

entonces usarias

```
[Route("CheckRoleExist/{n}")]
public JsonResult CheckRoleExist(string n)
{
    using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
    {
        var role = db.AspNetRoles.ToList<AspNetRoles>().Where(u => u.Name.Equals(n)).FirstOrDefault(); 

        return Json(role, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```